# iOS datasource and outlet references

Tags: swift, weak-references, custom-view, retain-cycle

I viewed some [Stanford iOS development classes](https://youtu.be/Dr0aFqOCnPg) on Youtube, and I found something that's not clear to me.
In the lecture the professor explains how to create custom views and custom data source classes, and the code is the following:

#### FaceView.swift

```
protocol FaceViewDataSource: class {
    // some stuff here
}

class FaceView: UIView {

    // some uninteresting properties here

    weak var dataSource: FaceViewDataSource?

    // other stuff here
}
```

#### HappinessViewController.swift

```
class HappinessViewController: UIViewController, FaceViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var faceView: FaceView!

    // other stuff here
}
```

The [professor said](https://youtu.be/Dr0aFqOCnPg?t=32m16s) that the `dataSource` property must be declared as a `weak` property to avoid retain cycles between the view and the view controller.

My question is: why do we have a retain cycle if we declare the `dataSource` property as strong? Since the `outlet` property is `weak`, isn't the retain cycle already avoided?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not. See the description below.

- View controller keeps strong reference to his view.
- View controller's view (not view controller) keeps strong reference to faceView.
- FaceView keeps strong reference to View controller.

Comment: Ok, so the view controller's view is actually the FaceView, isn't it? Sorry for multiple edits of this comment

Comment: No. You can read about view controller's view here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/view